# Why does bash shortcut not accept my ansible-playbook --limit wildcard *?

Tags: bash, ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to run an ansible-playbook via a bash shortcut, but getting an error.  When I run this command from the directory in long-hand (below), the playbook and my limits with wildcard * work fine; the playbook runs on all of the hosts starting with the BBCC names, i.e. BBCC01,BBCC02, etc.

[WORKS]

```
sparkles@Yo:~/myrepos/pre-post-role$ ansible-playbook run_pre_check.yml --limit 'BBCC*'
```

I have this bash script in my .bashrc file...

```
#precheck shortcut
    #to run, type "pre <whatever your limits will be>"
pre (){
    cd ~/myrepos/pre-post-role
    ansible-playbook run_pre_check.yml --limit $1
    cd
}
```

Normally if I do this command with specific limits, it works just fine.  Below are working examples:

[WORKS]
`pre BBCC01`
or
`pre BBCC01:BBCC02:BBCC03`

However, using the * wildcard as defined by ansible gives me an error.

[DOES NOT WORK]
`pre BBCC*`

Error from `pre BBCC*` is below:
**ansible-playbook: error: unrecognized arguments: BBCC01.zip BBCC_.zip**

Why doesn't this work?  Why is it looking for that zip file?  Is it something in my bash shortcut that I did wrong?  I read that it has to do with bash interpolation, but I'm not smart enough about bash to know what's happening.  Please educate me.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the argument to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard, just like you do when you run the command by hand. And you have to quote `$1` in the function to prevent it from being expanded there as well.

```
pre (){
    cd ~/myrepos/pre-post-role
    ansible-playbook run_pre_check.yml --limit "$1"
    cd
}

pre 'BBCC*'
```

Comment: It was the missing quotes in the bash!  Thank you for your help!  That fixed it!  Also, with the newly added quotes, I actually don't need the quotes in the command.  Just plain 

pre BBCC*

works great.  Thank you again!!! =D

Comment: That won't work if there are any `BBCC*` files in your current directory. The shell will expand the wildcard before calling the function.